# How to move stars ratings under add to cart button in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce and creating multi vendor website using Dokan plugin.

On single product pages, I want to move reviews star rating between the "Add to cart" button and the social icons but I don't know which hook I have to use for that purpose.

Below is a screenshot illustrating what I currently have;

[image: sceenshot]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385448/10221765).

Comment: **Note:** On e-commerce tagged questions (here "Woocommerce"), when "product" is the main component involved, like in this question, we use the tag "product" that refer to the main Object component and to the WordPress post-type… So please stop removing "product" tag.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec That seems like a pretty classic Meta tag to me (I could be wrong, though). FWIW, there's a [Meta discussion of this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285382/removing-this-tag-would-make-us-more-productive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - The following will work with most themes *(without related customizations on single product hooks or templates)*.

Here we change [`woocommerce_single_product_summary`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.6.0/templates/content-single-product.php#L49-L60) hooked functions priority for related function `woocommerce_template_single_rating()` to display star ratings just after single add to cart button, on single product pages:

- default priority for star ratings is **10**,
- default priority for add to cart button is **30**,
- new priority for for star ratings is **35** *(just after add to cart button)*.

The code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'change_stars_rating_location', 4 );
function change_stars_rating_location() {
    global $product;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 35 );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.